# Constructing a sequence with the following property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\beta_m\searrow 0$ be strictly decreasing, but with the rate and gaps arbitrary. Now I want to construct a sequence $\eta_m$ which also strictly decreases to $0$, with the following properties:

1. $\beta_m=O(\eta_m)$.
2. $m\eta_m\leq (m+1)\eta_{m+1}$, for all $m\ge 1$.
3. $\eta_m-\eta_{m+1}\geq \eta_{m+1}-\eta_{m+2}$, for all $m\geq 1$.

This seems rather technical, but let me include an example here: the sequence $2^{-m}$ satisfies 3 but not 2; the sequence $1/m$ satisfies both 2 and 3.

What I tried is the following:
Let $\eta_1=\beta_1$, $\eta_2=\max\{\beta_2,\eta_1/2\}$ so that $2\eta_2\geq 1\eta_1$ and $\eta_2\geq \beta_2$. For $m\geq 3$, we define 
    \begin{equation*}
\eta_m=\max\left\{\beta_m,\frac{m-1}m \eta_{m-1},2\eta_{m-1}-\eta_{m-2}\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Then 1,2,3 and that $\eta_m$ is strictly decreasing are easy to verify, but I cannot show that $\eta_m\to 0$. Is there another way of doing so? Or it is impossible for some ill-defined sequence $\beta_m$?